# Why is a split monomorphism (or split epimorphism) so called?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

There must surely be some folk-lore about this, but I can't recall the various sources I've looked at over the years ever explaining why split monos (or epics) are called *split*, of all things.

Is there is a simple story which makes the terminology seem natural?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about the *actual* reason, but my gut says it has to do with how they relate to split exact sequences, for instance of abelian groups.

A short exact sequence of abelian groups
$$
0\to A\to B\to C\to 0
$$
is called *split* iff $B\cong A\oplus C$ in a way that makes the two maps in the sequence into the canonical maps. And in this case the etymology seems pretty clear: $B$ splits into an $A$ component and a $C$ component.

And such a short exact sequence is split iff the map $B\to C$ is a split epimorphism iff $A\to B$ is a split monomorphism.

Comment: Product of groups is cartesian product. Coproduct of groups is free product. They coincide only for 0 or 1 arguments. The reason why SES of groups splits when either one of morphisms admits a section is that all monomorphisms and all epimorphisms are regular.

Comment: @xsnl You're right, I removed that.

Comment: Also SES of *groups* is split if middle term is a *semi*direct product, so this answer neither answers the question (which was about the ethymology), nor provides any mathematical knowledge.